# Why do i get whitelabel error page and how to resolve it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Whitelabel error occouring each time i hit localhost. How to resolve the error and move application further

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow, to get the best answers, please take the time to read the "how to ask a good question"-section https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you might get better answers then.

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller mapping for "/error" by implementing ErrorController.

```
@RestController
public class WelcomeController implements ErrorController{

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public String error() {
        return "Error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

Comment: That just resolves this but still i dont get the index page

Answer (score -1):

Try `application.properties` file by setting the `server.error.whitelabel.enabled` to `false`.

Comment: It eliminated the whitelabel page but error 404 still exists